# Image has unwanted padding/space around it

Tags: html, css, image, position, padding

I'm trying to position a circular image using css but it turn out it has some transparent space/padding around it!
Here's the image:
[image]

I tried `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;` but it isn't working! This space is messing the layout and position of every other element!

Here's the html(inside body tag):

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <DIV class="navbar">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="user">
                <p>"User's name"</p>
                <img src="images/girl.png">
            </div>
        </DIV>
    </div>

</body>
```

And here's the complete css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 2em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: rgba(29,33,61,0.5);
    padding: 0 60px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logo{
    width: 155px;
}
.logo img{
    width: 2.2em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 60px;
}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.user{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.user img{
    width: 270px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    margin:  0;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

How to deal with such scenarios? Any better alternative?

Comment: Are you taking into account the alpha channel/transparent background this PNG image has? If you're not, that's probably where the problem comes from.

Comment: I think I'm not! Thanks!.........But can you also provide the exact solution? Do I need to edit the image? Use another one? Actually I don't know much about that ***alpha channel/transparent background*** stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the fact that the image has a transparent background that you don't see, especially since you confirmed that you haven't taken it into account.

I edited the picture to crop out the background.

Try using this picture instead of the one in your post:

[image: Cropped-version-of-girl]